# Old computer, new install : ethernet and wifi not working

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint, ethernet

I got an old (5-6y at most I guess) computer from my company. They erased everything and just installed LMDE on it. Problem is, I can't seem to get any internet connection on it.

I searched a few sites and tried a thing or two... 
[1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2238503)
[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454529/no-wifi-or-ethernet-connection-after-installing-14-04)
[3](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243759)

I got this:

```
lspci -n | egrep '0200|0280' | awk '{print $3}'
14e4:167a
```

In case that helps, here is the result of ifconfig:

```
admin@neron ~ $ /sbin/ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:8b:83:80:67  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interruption:17 

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:8b:83:80:67  
          inet adr:169.254.7.187  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Masque:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interruption:17 

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
          RX bytes:476456 (465.2 KiB)  TX bytes:476456 (465.2 KiB)
```

I have no clue what to do with these...

Any help will  be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unless I'm blind, what kind of network cards does it use? If you can get the network card descriptions, we can get you links to some sort of drivers... unless I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @dooley_labs surely if the NIC was not working it would not bring up an eth0 device ?  It would seem that the computer is a Dell, and its finding the built-in NIC (as the 00:18:8b prefix in the MAC address attests)

Comment: I meant, could they possibly tell us if they knew what the cards are, not from the terminal output. If all else fails, I'm sure the cards have a serial printed on them, should they need to go that far. I'm no genius a the software side of linux's ipconfig output, but I know a few ways to fix the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like its not getting an IP address.  Try issuing the command

> dhclient eth0

From the command line.  If that works, you may want to edit /etc/network/interfaces with something like

```
auto eth0
iface eth inet dhcp
```